# When should I write take any chance in plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

I came across a shop selling the fruit jam that my sister had been looking for. But the fruit jam came in apple and peach flavours, I was not very sure which one my sister liked better, so I decided to buy both.
Now, given that situation, I want to explain why I bought both apple-flavoured and peach-flavoured jams to my sister:
I bought two fruit jams in different flavours because the jams would be sold out. I could not [take any chances / take any chance] .

Thank you

Kitty

Comment: Idiomatically, with ***any*** it's always plural - *[You must not] take **any chances***. Alternatively, it's singular with *[I didn't want to] take **the chance***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you suggesting my saying * I was careful not to take any chance of being late* would not be idiomatic?

Comment: @WS2: Perhaps my "always" was a bit OTT, but I don't like it much. Piling it on, [*take the chance of being*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22take+the+chance+of+being%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is almost 20 times more common in Google Books than [*take any chance of being*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22take+any+chance+of+being%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Personally, for that context I'd almost always use ***run the risk** of being [wrong]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not *...run **any** risk of being wrong*?

Comment: @WS2: Apparently ["the" is vastly more favoured than "any"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+the+risk+of%2Crun+any+risk+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crun%20the%20risk%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%20any%20risk%20of%3B%2Cc0), but there's a slight suggestion "any" was a (tiny) bit more likely in the past. Perhaps it's "regionally preserved" in your area, but it sounds just a tad odd/atypical to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I bought two fruit jams in different flavours because the jams would be sold out. I couldn't take any **chances**.

Alternatively,

> I bought two fruit jams in different flavours because the jams would be sold out. I couldn't take **chances**.

Even...

> I bought two fruit jams in different flavours because the jams would be sold out. I didn't want to take the **chance**.

Possibly...

> I bought two fruit jams in different flavours because the jams would be sold out. I didn't want to take a **chance**.

This last one doesn't sound quite right because the unfortunate event you're attempting to avoid is apparent: getting the wrong flavour and finding the right flavour sold out before you can get it. In the context, the indefinite article *a* doesn't appear to be appropriate. It's legal usage, but I don't think it works well here.

Comment: Unless you're a blindingly fast typist (I'm certainly not, as my handle here implies! :) I assume my comment and your answer were independent. But looking at it again now I see we both chose to illustrate "singular" usage with the *definite* article. I've already upvoted you anyway, but it might be worth extending your answer to show *indefinite article* usage (offhand I'm not sure which if any contexts are affected by whether it's *take **the** chance* or *take **a** chance*).

Comment: I am a fast typist, but I wasn't that fast. Your comment wasn't there when I posted my answer. I'll see about adding an example with the indefinite article.

Comment: I'm going AFK now, but I'll be interested to see if you can come up with any contexts where ***a/the*** aren't 100% interchangeable without affecting (implied) meaning.